# Power of 2 requirement when using python rfft

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm using numpy.fft in python to compute Fast Fourier Transforms. In particular, I'm using rfft as I have a real signal and don't need negative frequencies. My question is this: when I go to compute the FFT, does the length of my signal have to be a power of 2? My signal has 184320 points so I'm wondering if I need to truncate my signal at 131072 (2^17) or pad it with zeros so it has length 262144 (2^18)? My next step is to do windowing so I want to make sure I have performed my FFT correctly before I do anything further.

Comment: you need to understand the benefit of FFT in particular whether you care about possible changes in your signal across time ... to pick up variations across time you need to use as few samples as possible however this by definition will also increase the size of frequency increments across each array element returned from your FFT call ... experiment with this by using various sizes of array of samples you feed into FFT ... naturally using a smaller input array size will allow your run time execution to run faster ... I always use a power of 2 array size ... I believe FFT does as well but check

Comment: @ScottStensland, thanks for responding. For some context, I have a waveform with many periods captured within the 184320 points. Would you recommended truncating the signal after only a few periods? I tried applying a window to my signal and the amplitude of the fft is significantly different from the non-windowed version. Could this be because of how many periods I included?

Comment: I suggest you start with a known input signal lets say 2000 Hertz ... give yourself say one second of that signal which you use to populate your array which you feed into the FFT call ... this call will return back a new array of the same size as your input array ... each element of this returned array typically is nothing but a complex number ... iterate across this returned array and calculate the magnitude of each array element ... element 0 will be frequency 0 .. next element will denote a higher frequency ... this freq increment is calculated knowing your source array size and sample rate

Comment: once you have calculated the magnitude of each element plot to confirm you have a spike at your 2000 Hertz frequency

Comment: @ScottStensland, I have the source array size and sample rate of my signal. Should I use that to dictate how many periods I keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pad the signal.  The FFT implementation in NumPy is efficient for array lengths that are products of small prime factors, as noted in [README.md](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/fft/README.md), which says

> Efficient codelets are available for the factors:
>
> - 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11 for complex-valued FFTs
> - 2, 3, 4, 5 for real-valued FFTs

Your signal has length `184320 = 2**12 * 3**2 * 5`, so the FFT should be able to handle it efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Good to know that the FFT can handle my signal. If my signal has multiple periods, would it be best truncate after only a few periods for better results? I'm asking because applying windowing has significantly altered the amplitudes of the frequency components. I'm wondering if that could be impacted by my length of signal?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask that question over in the [DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site.